# How do I report a compile error if someone uses some classes from an external class library

Tags: c#, winforms, compiler-warnings

We bought a collection of Windows Forms controls. In order to extend their functionality have created their own equivalents by inheriting from the base. Is there any way to prohibit the use of basic controls (bought), and force our programmers to use ours.

I would like if someone uses the base control (I do not have access to its source), then the compiler  should report an error or warning and suggest to use my class (which inherits from the base).

Any ideas?

Comment: Make a seperate assembly for your "equivalents"; then reference this assembly in the "main project" and remove the reference to the third party library in "main project"; you will get compile errors

Comment: @Khurram - I was thinking that way too, but there's nothing stopping someone adding the 3rd party library back into the main project.

Comment: Third party library has to be included. We have made extensions only for 10 from 40 controls ... Already I was thinking to do as suggested by  Khurram Aziz

Comment: I tend you just run a find-replace on the entire solution on an occasional basis, if needed.

Comment: I am doing so now, just wondering if there are any built-in mechanisms that do it better and faster, and "automatically"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [write a custom FXCop rule](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/index.html) that would check this, then integrate this into your build process.  With VS2010, fxcop can be a part of every build if you so choose - or you can run it as part of your CI build or nightly build, what have you.

Comment: You have opened the "new worlds" in front of me. I've got to play with FxCop sdk, but when I clicked on the link you provided and saw examples I saw that this is probably what I'm looking for. Thank you ...

(I was already close to writing my own "compiler" in PostBuid :)

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this via a Post-build event.  Create a little exe, that opens up each project in your solution.  Reads each type in the assembly and makes sure no instances of the wrong types are created.